# Debating on networked storage

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, unity-game-engine, local

I'm working on a project that users will create content in and then will be able to use that same content in a different area. We already use AWS services for a lot of user data and will likely put this data there too. However, to eliminate a potential point of failure with having to upload and download the content, we are looking at storing this data on a local networked server as well and only using that local server for getting the data later on.

The main reason for choosing to do this is because the content that is being created is a few MB's (likely around 10 MB each, and there is potential to create multiple things). The thinking is that this would reduce the potential for issue mid-download.

I guess my question is, does this make sense to do? If not, what could be some potential alternatives? Maybe the file size isn't really much of an issue and we should just stick to AWS only?

If this is helpful, we are using Unity to develop the applications for this project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably just use S3 for storing the files. S3 promises [99.99% uptime](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/sla/) and [99.999999999% durability](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/).

Remember, objects in S3 are automatically replicated across servers in multiple, independent availability zones in AWS. It's going to take a lot of money and effort on your part (or your company) to get something you manage on premise to be at the same level of reliability as S3.

Comment: Yeah, this looks like the way to go. There seems to not be much, if any, advantage to using a local server instead of S3 here. Thank you